# Why I am getting the fetch is not defined error?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, sendgrid

I have *tried* to create a custom email receipt template with SendGrid using commercejs webhooks, by following [this](https://commercejs.com/blog/integrating-sendgrid-for-ecommerce-email-receipts/) tutorial. I have uploaded [this github repository](https://github.com/sepi2048/Test-PL/blob/main/functions/email.js) to
[this test Netlify site](https://stoic-payne-386d66.netlify.app/). The main code is `/functions/email.js` I am pretty sure my `.env` variables are correct, still no receipt emails are received and probably send. When checking the Netlify function email log says:

```
5:55:03 PM: f7c003e5 ERROR  Invoke Error    {"errorType":"ReferenceError","errorMessage":"fetch is not defined","stack":["ReferenceError: fetch is not defined","    at Runtime.exports.handler (/var/task/email.js:30:22)","    at Runtime.handleOnce (/var/runtime/Runtime.js:66:25)"]}
5:55:03 PM: f7c003e5 Duration: 2.24 ms  Memory Usage: 52 MB
```

However my `package.json` `dependencies` look like this:

```
  "dependencies": {
    "@chec/commerce.js": "2.2.0",
    "@hookform/error-message": "0.0.5",
    "@sendgrid/mail": "^7.4.7",
    "@stripe/react-stripe-js": "1.1.2",
    "@stripe/stripe-js": "1.11.0",
    "autoprefixer": "10.0.4",
    "classcat": "4.1.0",
    "framer-motion": "2.9.4",
    "next": "10.0.2",
    "next-google-fonts": "1.2.1",
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "pdf-lib": "^1.16.0",
    "postcss": "8.1.14",
    "react": "17.0.1",
    "react-dom": "17.0.1",
    "react-hook-form": "6.11.5",
    "react-toastify": "6.1.0",
    "use-debounce": "^7.0.0"
  },
```

Therefore it's confusing why I am getting the *fetch is not* defined error. Also, I am also confused about how to implement the headers correctly, because the tutorial did not specify how. So I just added the headers like this, without knowing if this is the way to do it:

```
let headers = {
    "Accept": "application/json",
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
};

let sgheaders = {
    Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SENDGRID_SECRET}`,
    "Content-Type": "application/json",
};
```

In the code currently uploaded to my netlify site, I had to change the `export default async function handler(req, res) {`

to

`exports.handler = async function(req, res) {` according to the Netlify functions documentation the Netlify functions documentation. (because of *"errorMessage": "SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'export'"*)

```
// Create the API endpoint function with a req and res parameter
exports.handler = async function(req, res) {

    const checSecretAPIKey = process.env.CHEC_SECRET_KEY;


    let headers = {
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };


//export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (!req.body || req.httpMethod !== 'POST') {
        return {
            status: 405,
            headers,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                status: 'Invalid HTTP method',
            }),
        }
    }

    const { data } = JSON.parse(req.body);

    // Request for your merchant information so that you can use your email
    // to include as the 'from' property to send to the SendGrid API
    const merchant = fetch(`${process.env.CHEC_API_URL}/v1/merchants`, {
        headers: {
            'X-Authoriza†ion': process.env.CHEC_SECRET_KEY,
        },
    }).then((response) => response.json);

    // Extract the signature from the registered `orders.create` webhook
    const { signature } = data;

    delete data.signature;

    // Your Chec webhook signing key, from the Chec Dashboard webhooks view
    const webHookSigningKey = 'KEJlxz6cIlrWIpsX5jypcMeGl2uh7jJg';


    // Verify the signature
    const expectedSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', webHookSigningKey)
        .update(JSON.stringify(data))
        .digest('hex');
    if (expectedSignature !== signature) {
        console.error('Signature mismatched, skipping.')
    }

    // Verify the age of the request to make sure it isn't more than 5 minutes old.
    if (new Date(data.created * 1000) < new Date() - 5 * 60 * 1000) {
        console.error('Webhook was sent too long ago, could potentially be fake, ignoring');
    }

    // Because you will need to list out the order line items, map through the returned line items
    // and structure out the data you need to display in the email receipt for your customer
    // Note that we are keeping the data structure minimal here
    const orderLineItems = data.payload.order.line_items.map((lineItem) => ({
        text: lineItem.product_name,
        price: lineItem.line_total.formatted_with_symbol,
    }));

    // Signature is verified, continue to send data to SendGrid
    // Create the email object payload to fire off to SendGrid
    const emailPayload = {
        to: data.payload.customer.email,
        from: merchant.support_email,
        subject: `Thank you for your order ${data.payload.customer.firstname}`,
        text: `Your order number is ${data.payload.customer_reference}`,
        // SendGrid expects a JSON blog containing the dynamic order data your template will use
        // More information below in 'What's next?' on how to configure your dynamic template in SendGrid
        // The property key names will depend on what dynamic template you create in SendGrid
        dynamic_template_data: {
            total: data.payload.order.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol,
            items: orderLineItems,
            receipt: true,
            name: data.payload.shipping.name,
            address01: data.payload.shipping.street,
            city: data.payload.shipping.town_city,
            state: data.payload.shipping.county_state,
            zip : data.payload.shipping.postal_zip_code,
            orderId : data.payload.id,
        },
        // In addition to specifying the dynamic template data, you need to specify the template ID. This comes from your SendGrid dashboard when you create you dynamic template
    // https://mc.sendgrid.com/dynamic-templates
        template_id: 'd-xxx'
    }


    let sgheaders = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SENDGRID_SECRET}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };

    let response = {};
    try {
        // Call the SendGrid send mail endpoint
        response = await sgMailClient.send(emailPayload);
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: sgheaders,
            body: 'Email sent!'
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error', err)
    }
    // Return the response from the request
    return res.status(200).json(response);
}
```

Need some advice on how to get this code to actually work, the tutorial seems to be uncompleted or I might have misunderstood some curtail details.

**UPDATE** (Working code below)
Had to use axios instead of node.fetch (thanks @hotcakedev) wehn deplodey on netlify. Also other changes to the code in order to make it work with commerce.js (see working code for detalis)

```
const axios = require('axios');
const sgMailClient = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMailClient.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
// Includes crypto module
const crypto = require('crypto');


// Create the API endpoint function with a req and res parameter
exports.handler = async function(req, res) {

//export default async function handler(req, res) {
    if (!req.body || req.httpMethod !== 'POST') {
        return {
            status: 405,
            headers: {},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                status: 'Invalid HTTP method',
            }),
        }
    }

    const data = JSON.parse(req.body);

    // Request for your merchant information so that you can use your email
    // to include as the 'from' property to send to the SendGrid API
    const merchant = axios.get(`${process.env.CHEC_API_URL}/v1/merchants`, {
        headers: {
            'X-Authorization': process.env.CHEC_SECRET_KEY,
            "Accept": "application/json",
            "Content-Type": "application/json",
        },
    }).then((response) => response.json);

    //console.log(data);

    // Extract the signature from the registered `orders.create` webhook
    const { signature } = data;

    delete data.signature;

    // Your Chec webhook signing key, from the Chec Dashboard webhooks view
    const webHookSigningKey = 'KEJlxz6cIlrWIpsX5jypcMeGl2uh7jJg';


    // Verify the signature
    const expectedSignature = crypto.createHmac('sha256', webHookSigningKey)
        .update(JSON.stringify(data))
        .digest('hex');
    if (expectedSignature !== signature) {
        console.error('Signature mismatched, skipping.')
    }

    // Verify the age of the request to make sure it isn't more than 5 minutes old.
    if (new Date(data.created * 1000) < new Date() - 5 * 60 * 1000) {
        console.error('Webhook was sent too long ago, could potentially be fake, ignoring');
    }

    // Because you will need to list out the order line items, map through the returned line items
    // and structure out the data you need to display in the email receipt for your customer
    // Note that we are keeping the data structure minimal here
    const orderLineItems = data.payload.order.line_items.map((lineItem) => ({
        text: lineItem.product_name,
        price: lineItem.line_total.formatted_with_symbol,
    }));





    // Signature is verified, continue to send data to SendGrid
    // Create the email object payload to fire off to SendGrid
    const emailPayload = {
        to: data.payload.customer.email,
        from: data.payload.merchant.support_email,
        subject: `Thank you for your order ${data.payload.customer.firstname}`,
        text: `Your order number is ${data.payload.customer_reference}`,

        // SendGrid expects a JSON blog containing the dynamic order data your template will use
        // More information below in 'What's next?' on how to configure your dynamic template in SendGrid
        // The property key names will depend on what dynamic template you create in SendGrid
        dynamic_template_data: {
            total: data.payload.order.subtotal.formatted_with_symbol,
            items: orderLineItems,
            receipt: true,
            name: data.payload.billing.name,
            address01: data.payload.billing.street,
            city: data.payload.billing.town_city,
            state: data.payload.billing.county_state,
            zip : data.payload.billing.postal_zip_code,
            orderId : data.payload.id,
        },
        // In addition to specifying the dynamic template data, you need to specify the template ID. This comes from your SendGrid dashboard when you create you dynamic template
    // https://mc.sendgrid.com/dynamic-templates
        template_id: 'd-xxx'
    };

    /*let sgheaders = {
        Authorization: `Bearer ${process.env.SENDGRID_SECRET}`,
        "Content-Type": "application/json",
    };*/

    let response = {};
    try {
        // Call the SendGrid send mail endpoint
        response = await sgMailClient.send(emailPayload);
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            headers: {},
            body: JSON.stringify({
                status: 'Email sent!',
            }),
        }
    } catch (err) {
        console.error('Error from function: ', err)
        console.error(err.response.body);
        console.log("Payload content: ", emailPayload );
    }
    // Return the response from the request
    //return res.status(200).json(response);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to integrate sendgrid using Rest API, I suggest you to use [axios](https://www.npmjs.com/package/axios).

So in your case,

```
    import axios from 'axios';
    ...
    const merchant = axios.get(`${process.env.CHEC_API_URL}/v1/merchants`, {
        headers: {
            'X-Authoriza†ion': process.env.CHEC_SECRET_KEY,
        },
    }).then((response) => response.json);
    ...
```

Comment: This actually solved the `.fetch` issue. Now I keep getting this error: `"errorMessage": "Header name must be a valid HTTP token [\"X-Authoriza†ion\"]"` I am quite sure I have defined my Environment variables correctly on my Netlify dashboard  [(screenshot)](https://ibb.co/2kqdrDb) is there any other reason why this error can occur?

Comment: @Fjott Does the variables work on your local environment?

Comment: As you can see there is a typo in the `X-Authoriza†ion` for some reason there is a `†` instead of `t` this caused the error msg.  I also had to change `const {data} = JSON.parse(req.body);` to `const data = JSON.parse(req.body);` Now I am getting a `ResponseError: Bad Request` at the Sendgrid request and a `"errorMessage":"res.status is not a function"`

Comment: Can you try this? ```const merchant = await axios({
      method: 'get',
      url: `${process.env.CHEC_API_URL}/v1/merchants`,
      headers: {
        'Authorization': `Bearer ${process.env.CHEC_SECRET_KEY}`,
        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      },
    }).then(response => response.json)```

Comment: I basically had to comment out the last line `return res.status(200).json(response);` in order to get rid of the  `"errorMessage":"res.status is not a function"` not exactly sure why this solved the problem, but I think this line might have been redundant with the `.try return` a few lines up - correct me if I am wrong. I Also had to make some few other changes, have updated the main code

Answer (score 1):

Twilio SendGrid developer evangelist here.

You have installed node-fetch to the project, but the tutorial did not include requiring the library into the function to use it. So you need to require `node-fetch`.

The tutorial also fails to require the SendGrid library and set the API key. You should set your SendGrid API key in the environment in Netlify, called something like `SENDGRID_API_KEY`. Then add the following to the top of your function:

```js
const fetch = require("node-fetch");
const sgMailClient = require("@sendgrid/mail");
sgMailClient.setApiKey(process.env.SENDGRID_API_KEY);
```

As for the headers that you are asking about, they are the response headers that your function returns in response to the incoming HTTP request. What you return depends on how you are calling this function, but you *should not* return your SendGrid API Key in the headers.

While you are getting the function working, I would recommend setting the return headers to an empty object until you work out what Content-Type you want to set (the response body is "Email sent!" right now, which would be `text/plain` but that's not super useful in the front end) and what other headers you may or may not need.